# Converting JPEG to PNG in VB.NET(Saved output has no extension)

Tags: vb.net, png, jpeg, converters

This is my code in converting my image

```
Public Sub ConvertImage(ByVal Filename As String, _
      ByVal DesiredFormat As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat, _
      ByVal NewFilename As String)
        NewFilename = "ConvertedToPNG-" + NewFilename + "-" + Format(Date.Now, "MMMMddyyyyhhmmtt")
        Try
            Dim imgFile As System.Drawing.Image = _
              System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Filename)
            imgFile.Save(txtPNGFileDestination.Text & "\" & NewFilename, DesiredFormat)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

It has runs properly but the saved image hasn't have a PNG file extension thus making it just a file. Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just append `.png` to `NewFilename`

Comment: so you mean is it really ok that I manually add the extension?

Comment: Sure. I mean, what is a file extension really? Isn't it just a piece of the filename that the OS or program gives meaning to?

Comment: The original is in JPG format, I thought the output should be in png format already when it is executed

Comment: changing the filename (or extension) won't change the format of the file. Even without an extension it's still a PNG image.

Comment: guess manual input of the extension it is, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the extension to NewFileName. You'll also need to declare NewFileName "ByRef":

```
Public Sub ConvertImage(ByVal Filename As String, ByVal DesiredFormat As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat, ByRef NewFilename As String)
  NewFilename = "ConvertedToPNG-" + NewFilename + "-" + Format(Date.Now, "MMMMddyyyyhhmmtt") & "." & DesiredFormat.ToString
```